# C++ Sys/Stat.h has an error?

Tags: c++, c, linux, standard-library

I'm trying to create a cross-platform program. I just created a class and made a function which gets the path of the current user. I wanted to use that path later. But somehow I get these errors :

"/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h:-1: In member function 'void FileManager::p_getfilepath()':"

"/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h:105: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant"

"/home/david/VocabularyTrainer/filemanager.cpp:31: error: expected '}' at end of input"

btw the 31th line is the last line here in this code :

```
void FileManager::p_getfilepath()
{
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif

#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct passwd *p;
uid_t  uid;

if ((p = getpwuid(uid = geteuid())) == NULL)
{
    QMessageBox* mb;
    mb->setText("");
    mb->exec();
    delete mb;
}
else
{
    filepath = p->pw_dir;
}
#endif
}
```

Anyone knows what's wrong? I'm on linux mint.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be including a header *inside* a method like that?  I'm almost certain that won't turn out well.

Comment: I can only include that header if it's on a linux or unix system.

Comment: That's fine, but why would you want to do it *inside* the method?

Comment: Yeah just realized that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By including your headers **inside** your class functions, you're making everything in the header a part of the function.

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif

#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
#include <sys/stat.h>
#endif

void FileManager::p_getfilepath()
{
#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX

    struct passwd *p;
    uid_t  uid;

    if ((p = getpwuid(uid = geteuid())) == NULL)
    {
        QMessageBox* mb;
        mb->setText("");
        mb->exec();
        delete mb;
    }
    else
    {
        filepath = p->pw_dir;
    }

#endif
}
```